# Place a button and assign a macro to it

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to create a button.

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(264, 230.25, 127.5, 11.25).Select
Selection.OnAction = "choose_worksheet_1"
Range("C16").Select
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(264, 230.25, 127.5, 11.25).Select
Selection.Characters.Text = "Next step (2)"
With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font
    .Name = "Tahoma"
    .FontStyle = "Standaard"
    .Size = 8
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    '.ThemeColor = 2
    '.TintAndShade = 0
    '.ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
End With
```

This all works but the thing is that I would like to add a macro to it straight away. Could anybody tell me how I can a macro to the button, for example "Macro2"

Comment: change `Selection.OnAction = "choose_worksheet_1"` to `Selection.OnAction = "Macro2"`